# Running into "AmqpException: PublisherCallbackChannel is closed" exception while acking events

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

We are using spring-amqp library to consume messages from RabbitMQ and sometimes when we are acking the messages, we are running into the following exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: PublisherCallbackChannel is closed
  at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:908)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy265.basicAck(Unknown Source)
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.ackBatch(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:105)
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.executeBatch(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:88)
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.access$300(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:27)
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener$BatchExecutor.run(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:161)
  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
  at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Any ideas?

For reference: We are using RabbitMQ 3.5.6 & spring-amqp: 1.6.1.RELEASE

Comment: Try to increase the `CachingConnectionFactory.channelCacheSize`. By default it is `25`. The extra channels are closed after 5 seconds during their `physicalClose()`. The cached channel are just returned to pool.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Our current channelCacheSize is set to 25k, just verified it. If I were to buffer messages and the channel, and let's say I ack the messages after 5 seconds, would it result in this exception? Also, is the 5 seconds configurable?

Comment: Correct. Do you really use `cacheMode == CacheMode.CHANNEL` ?

Comment: Yes, verified that we use cacheMode is set to Channel.

Comment: OK. Any chances to upgrade to the latest version: https://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/, at least `1.7.7`? We may have some fix there on the matter...

Comment: We are currently running into this issue in Production, so it will take a bit of time to upgrade. Here's the gist of our code of where we are buffering messages, we are running into this exception when acking the messages.

https://gist.github.com/bin01/7b36cf23a8457772e6c59b764d5c6dcc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171728/discussion-between-snehal-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Yes, everything looks good. May you say what is that `Done executing the batch in {}ms` ? Although you do that in the the same `onMessage()` thread, so channel must not be closed so far. Sorry, no ideas. That might be great to have some simple project on GitHub to reproduce and play.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I am just logging the time the sub-class implementation took to process the batch of messages.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Is there a way to configure the time when the channels are closed? Can we increase it from default 5 secs to 20 secs? If yes, what is the property?

Comment: No, it's not configurable: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.java#L1147. Do you confirm that the problem if exactly with that long situation?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Looking at the logs it appears that if the sub-classes doExecuteBatch takes more than 5 seconds, then the channel is getting closed.

Comment: See my answer; but, more importantly, you shouldn't call `basicAck` on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 second delay mentioned by @ArtemBilan is a cushion to keep the channel open after a physical close, in case there are pending publisher acks to receive. 5 seconds is more than enough for that.

It is not at all relevant here; listener containers NEVER close their channel(s) until they are shut down, and even then the close is done by the listener thread after it exits your method.

If you are getting channel closed errors while acking, it means something else closed the channel; perhaps a dropped connection.

I suggest you look earlier in the log and/or the rabbit server log to see if there are any clues.

1.6.1 is nearly 2 years old.

If this has only just started happening, I suspect something else in the app/environment has changed.

I presume your concurrency is 1 - otherwise what you are doing is bad since each thread has its own channel.

**EDIT**

I just noticed you are using an executor - you can't do that; channels are not thread-safe; you should execute the batch on the listener thread.

```
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.ackBatch(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:105)
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.executeBatch(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:88)
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.access$300(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:27)
  at com.zeus.server.queue.AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener$BatchExecutor.run(AbstractBatchingQueueMessageListener.java:161)
```

https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#channel-threads

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented this batched message processing https://gist.github.com/bin01/7b36cf23a8457772e6c59b764d5c6dcc   based on your response given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453667/47361 

Should I not ack the message from another thread ever? Also, as you guessed, we have a concurrency of 1 and we use several SimpleMessageListenerContainer to achieve better throughput.

Comment: Well, I did add a comment later that says using an idle event to trigger the time-based processing would make things a lot simpler. The rabbit guys advise not using channels on multiple threads. YMMV. Using multiple containers won't help unless your listener is a prototype-scoped bean (so each container gets a distinct instance). I still don't understand why you are getting closed channels though, unless you are attempting to ack after the container has been stopped.

Comment: Wouldn't we receive the "idle event trigger" from another thread as well, so I think I would still have to lock right or am I missing something (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#idle-containers)? I am using prototype scope to ensure each container gets a distinct instance. We are definitely not calling ack after the container is stopped. 

We only have one connection to RabbitMQ for the entire process, is this the right configuration or should we use a pool of connections? We will try to upgrade spring-amqp to 1.7.7 and see if it helps.

Comment: The idle event is published by the thread that owns the channel. One connection is fine; I can assure you that as long as the container is active the channel will remain open, unless closed by some other mechanism (dropped connection etc).

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem because double ack in the code:

```
if(null != jsonObject){
    //some code
    channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
}
channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
```

just remove first ack solved my problem!